# Запоминание введенных пользователем данных в MySQL таблицу

Tags: php, html, sql

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть необходимость передать в MySQL таблицу данные, введенные им в input. Javascript не подходит, так как нужно сразу передать данные на сервер. Не понимаю, как считать данные, введенные в input и в том же файле отправить их. Я начинающий, поэтому, возможно что-то не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от того, как вы хотите это делать.
Самое простое, это с помощью джаваскрипта прочитать файл, потом отправить (например ajax'ом) текст на сервер и там его поместить в базу.
Мождно джаваскриптом отправить сам файл на сервер и потом уже на сервер обработать его и поместить данные в базу.
Вот пример чтения файла: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14446538/4998931
И т.д. Слишком общий у вас вопрос.

UPDATE (После разьяснения, что имелся в виду value в элементе input):

Получаем текст из инпута например так:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("bigTextHolder").value;
```

Теперь у вас в `txt` находится весь текст из контейнера (или нет, по какой-то из причин, так что проверяем)

```
if(txt && txt.length > 0)
{
    //отправляем txt аяксом (ajax)
}
```

Вот отсюда взял пример: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Если используете другой фреймворк (jQuery например или еще что), то в гуглах пишем:

```
{название фреймворка} получить value из input
```

Comment: Javascript не подходит. вопрос поменял.

Comment: Только javascript и подходит! :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Понял.